# 2Sum, 3Sum, 4Sum ........kSum with HashSet (HashTable) solution

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, hashmap, hashtable

I am solving a problem. The problem is given below --

> *Given an array nums of n integers and an integer target, are there elements a, b, c, and d in nums such that a + b + c + d = target? Find all unique quadruplets in the array which gives the sum of target.*

**Note:**

The solution set must not contain duplicate quadruplets.

Given array `nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]`, and `target = -1`.

A solution set is:

`[[-4,0,1,2],[-1,-1,0,1]]`

My code is given below for the that problem-

```
class Solution {

List<List<Integer>> output=new ArrayList();
    

public List<List<Integer>> fourSum(int[] nums, int target) {

    Arrays.sort(nums);
    
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(i==0 || nums[i-1]!=nums[i]){
            for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){                
                if(j==1 || nums[j-1]!=nums[j]){
                    calculate(nums, i, j, target);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
        
}

public void calculate(int[] nums, int i, int j, int target){
    
    Set<Integer> hashSet=new HashSet();
    for(int k=j+1; k<nums.length;k++){
        int vector=target-nums[i]-nums[j]-nums[k];
        if(hashSet.contains(vector)){
            output.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i], nums[j], nums[k],vector));
            while(k+1<nums.length && nums[k]==nums[k+1]){
                k++;                                        
            }
                
        }            
        hashSet.add(nums[k]);
    }
    
}
```

}

My output is: `[[-4,0,2,1]]`

But expected output is: `[[-4,0,1,2],[-1,-1,0,1]]`

Please help!

To solve this problem following steps I have performed..

```
 A) For the main function:

     1. Sort the input array nums.
     2. Iterate through the array for 2 times (i, j):
         If the current value is greater than zero, break from the 
         loop. Remaining values cannot sum to zero.
         If the current value is the same as the one before, skip it.
         Otherwise, call twoSum for the current position i.

  B) For calculate function:

      1. For each index k > j in A:
      2. Compute complement vector = target -nums[i] - nums[j].
      3. If complement exists in hashset seen:
      4. We found a triplet - add it to the result res.
      5. Increment k while the next value is the same as before to 
         avoid duplicates in the result.

   C) Add nums[k] to hashset seen
   D) Return the result output.
```

Comment: Can you please explain your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is at line `(j==1 || nums[j-1]!=nums[j])` & `(i==0 || nums[i-1]!=nums[i])`

```
static List<List<Integer>> output;
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
    output = new ArrayList<>();
    fourSum(new int[]{0,0,0,0},0);
    System.out.println(output);
}

public static void fourSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){
            calculate(nums, i, j, target);
        }
    }
}

public static void calculate(int[] nums, int i, int j, int target){
    Set<Integer> hashSet=new HashSet();
    for(int k=j+1; k<nums.length;k++){
        int vector=target-nums[i]-nums[j]-nums[k];
        if(hashSet.contains(vector)){
            output.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i], nums[j], nums[k],vector));
            while(k+1<nums.length && nums[k]==nums[k+1]){
                k++;                                        
            }
        }            
        hashSet.add(nums[k]);
    }
}
```

input:{0,0,0,0}, target:0, output: `[[0,0,0,0]]`

input:{-1,0,1,2,-1,-4}, target:-1, output: `[[-4, 0, 2, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 0]]`

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine for that input. But there is a new error. If I provide the Input - [0,0,0,0] and target=0 then it gives me the [] output. But expected output will be [[0,0,0,0]]

Comment: By using the similar approach I am able to solve 3sum. I have added one more loop and trying to solve 4sum. Is this approach is ok to solve the problem. I am still getting the error.

Comment: code snippet will not work for duplicate elements since you are using `nums[i-1]!=nums[i]` condition

Comment: So, What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a follow-up of 3Sum. 4Sum and 3Sum are very similar; the difference is that we are looking for unique quadruplets instead of triplets.

Following a similar logic, we can implement 5Sum by wrapping 4Sum in another loop. But what about the 6Sum, 7Sum and so on. It's better we should go for kSum solution. Following code will work for 2Sum, 3Sum, 4Sum and so on.

```
class Solution {

 public List<List<Integer>> fourSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    int start=0;
    int k=4;
    return this.kSum(nums,target,start,k);            
 }

 public List<List<Integer>> kSum(int[] nums, int target, int start, int k){
    
    List<List<Integer>> output= new ArrayList<>();
    
    if(start==nums.length || nums[start] * k>target || nums[nums.length-1]*k<target)
        return output;
    
    if(k==2)
       return this.twoSum(nums,target,start);
    for(int i=start;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(i==start || nums[i-1]!=nums[i])
            for(var set: kSum(nums, target-nums[i],i+1,k-1)){
                output.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(nums[i])));
                output.get(output.size()-1).addAll(set);
            }
        
    }
    return output;
    
    
 }

 public List<List<Integer>> twoSum(int[] nums, int Target, int start){
    
    
    List<List<Integer>> output=new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
    
    for(int i=start;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(output.isEmpty() || output.get(output.size()-1).get(1) !=nums[i]){
            int vector=Target-nums[i];
            if(set.contains(vector)){
                output.add(Arrays.asList(vector, nums[i]));
            }
        }
        set.add(nums[i]);
    }
    
    return output;
 }

}
```